# how to call variable in function object javascript

Tags: javascript

Im learning js , can u help me how to call variable js in object function

example

```
var obj = {
    a : 'foo',
    b : function(){
        var ab = a + "bar"; <-- how to call var 'ab' outside var obj ..
        alert(ab)
    }
}

console.log(ab);
```

thanks

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You declared `ab` as a variable inside the closure of function `b`. What are you actually trying to do here? You could return `ab` from the function `b` or you could make it a member your obj, or you can make it global.

Comment: i need content of var 'ab' in the object..

Comment: @AlfathDirk may I ask why the unaccept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to call it unless your function returns that var. Like this:

```
var obj = {
    a : 'foo',
    b : function(){
        var ab = a + "bar"; // <-- how to call var 'ab' outside var obj ..
        alert(ab);
        return ab; // this is the key
    }

}
```

Then, to call it, just use:

```
var myNewVar = obj.b();
```

**Note**: as Benjamin Gruenbaum pointed out (I thought it was obvious, but yeah, it should be mentioned to a beginner definitely), `myNewVar` won't be a reference of your `ab` variable, but only have its value.

Comment: Since strings are values in JS `myNewVar` is not ab, but just its value. That's not the same. The correct answer is there is no way to modify it from outside the function.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's very true, I'll add it to my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to invoke it as global variable.

```
var ab;
var obj = { a : 'foo', b : function(){ ab = a + "bar";}
console.log(ab);
```

or probably you need to output it by return

```
var obj = { a : 'foo', b : function(){ var ab = a + "bar"; return ab;}
console.log(obj.b());
```